# Exit a bash function on non zero exit

Tags: linux, bash

For bash scripts, one would use `set -e`.

Is there a way to get the same behavior in functions? Using `set -e` will take the entire shell with it, which I don't want.

Comment: Do you mean something that `return`s from the function when an error is encountered?

Comment: Recommended reading: [BashFAQ#105: Why doesn't set -e do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)